# Can anyone help me remove numeric data from string by using re.sub in Python?

Tags: python, python-re

I am working with text files and have data like below. I want to remove only things like 1 and 0.6271, and not T123 from data.

```
page_data=1 0.6271 bacs T123 Biologically Active Substance
page_data =re.sub(r"", '  ',page_data)
```

Required output:

```
bacs T123 Biologically Active Substance
```

Comment: Why you expect your regex (which is an empty string...) to work? Why do you insist on using `re`? What's wrong with something like `' '.join(page_data.split()[2:])`? Or even `page_data.split(' ', 2)[-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the @gmdev answer but also want to point out the regex answer in case of regex necessity.

Regex(That only matches float and integers in the string):

Use this regex to exclude matched part(integer and floats):
[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/5qg40R/1)

`(^|\s)([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)`

Python usage:

```
import re

re.sub("(^|\s)([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)", '', "1 0.6271 bacs T123 Biologically Active Substance")
```

**Input:** 1 0.6271 bacs T123 Biologically Active Substance

**Output:** bacs T123 Biologically Active Substance

Comment: thanks you its work for my scenario. God bless you. thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

As the comments pointed out, using `re` might over-complicate things for you and it is not very necessary here. If using `re` is not required, for something like this, you can do a simple `try except` statement.

```
def removenumeric(string):
    newstr = []
    for word in string.split():
        try:
            float(word)
        except ValueError:
            newstr.append(word)
    return ' '.join(newstr)
```

Output:

```
bacs T123 Biologically Active Substance
```

You can't use `.isnumeric()` here because it will return false for strings that are floats. This is why using `float(word)` is necessary for creating the accurate output.